# Windows 7 Not Keeping The Time Upon Reboot

Tags: windows-7, sync, time

I have Windows 7 Ultimate from TechNet, and for some reason, whenever I restart, I must manually sync my PC time with a time server.  The system probably syncs the time eventually, but why doesn't Windows "save" the time it receives for future reboots?

I have an Intel iMac running Windows 7 Ultimate.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

When you are using OSX, does it remember the time between reboots?

Personally, make sure you have all the drivers updated and double check all the settings in Bootcamp.

Windows does not really "keep" the time, it is stored in the BIOS/CMOS, and if your machine is loosing it, it could mean a flat internal battery or something more sinister.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Boot Camp drivers?  Sounds like you're hitting the old "Mac OS X stores system time in UTC but Windows stores system time in local time" issue.  The Boot Camp drivers do . . . something to fix that.